# Where do $k$-invariants actually live?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory, k-theory

I'm looking at [Brunner's version of Adam's computation](http://www.rrb.wayne.edu/papers/Cohom_ku.pdf) showing $H^*(ku;\Bbb Z_2)=\mathcal A/\mathcal A(Q_0,Q_1)$. Here $ku$ is the connective cover of the usual complex $K$-theory spectrum $K=KU$. The first several spaces are
$$ku=(BU\times\Bbb Z,U,BU,SU,BSU,BSU\langle 5\rangle,\ldots).$$
Bott periodicity shows $\pi_*ku=\Bbb Z[\eta]$, where $\eta$ has degree $2$ and corresponds to the Hopf map. From this we can construct a Whitehead tower for $ku$:

\begin{array}{ccccc}
& & \vdots & &\\
& & \downarrow & & \\
\Sigma H\Bbb Z &\longrightarrow & \Sigma^4 ku &\longrightarrow & \Sigma^4 H\Bbb Z\\
& & \phantom{\eta}\downarrow\eta & & \\
\Sigma^{-1}H\Bbb Z&\longrightarrow & \Sigma^2 ku &\longrightarrow & \Sigma^2H\Bbb Z \\
& & \phantom{\eta}\downarrow\eta & & \\
& & ku& \longrightarrow & H\Bbb Z
\end{array}

Now my understanding is that the $0$-th $k$-invariant is classified by $ku\to H\Bbb Z$ and lives in $H^0ku$. This would just be $k_0=1\in H^0ku$. The next $k$-invariant should be classified by $\Sigma^2ku\to \Sigma^2H\Bbb Z$, giving a class in $H^2\Sigma^2ku$.

But Bruner refers to the first $k$-invariant as (induced by) the composition
$$\Sigma^{-1}H\Bbb Z\to \Sigma^2ku\to\Sigma^2H\Bbb Z,$$
and thus an element of $H^2(\Sigma^{-1}H\Bbb Z)=H^3H\Bbb Z$. I cannot see why it makes sense to call this "the" first $k$-invariant. Adams uses the same language, simply asserting that the first $k$-invariant of $ku$ lives in $H^3H\Bbb Z$. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here and would appreciate some explanation or reference.